# Pass string from fragment to non-activity class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this Volley GET request class:

```
public class VolleyGetHeaders {
private static final String TAG = "VolleyGet";
private static VolleyGetHeaders instance = null;

//for Volley API
public RequestQueue requestQueue;

private VolleyGetHeaders(Context context)
{
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());

    return;
}

public static synchronized VolleyGetHeaders getInstance(Context context)
{
    if (null == instance)
        instance = new VolleyGetHeaders(context);
    return instance;
}

public static synchronized VolleyGetHeaders getInstance()
{
    if (null == instance)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(VolleyGetHeaders.class.getSimpleName() +
                " is not initialized, call getInstance(...) first");
    }
    return instance;

}

public void VolleyGETHeaders(String domain, String api, final CustomListener<String> listener){

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, domain +api,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response);
                    if(null != response)
                        listener.getResult(response);

                    return;

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (null != error.networkResponse)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG + ": ", "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                        //listener.getResult(false);
                    }
                }
            })
    {

        @Override
        public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers= new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization",finalToken);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(sr);

}
}
```

And in my fragment I want to send my string finalToken into the class to set as header:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences sp=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("domainname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String domain = sp.getString("domainname", "");
    SharedPreferences sp1=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("FINALTOKEN", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String finalToken = sp1.getString("FINALTOKEN","");
    VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance(getActivity());
    VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance().VolleyGETHeaders(domain, api, new CustomListener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void getResult(String result){
            if (!result.isEmpty())
            {
                Log.e("customer info", result);
                System.out.println("customer info----------->" + result);
            }
        }

    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account, container, false);
```

My question is how can I pass finalToken to my non-activity class, as you can see I have already made final a shared preference but I don't know how to retrieve it in my non-activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Declare one variable(finalToken) Non activity class : VolleyGetHeaders

```
public class VolleyGetHeaders {
private static final String TAG = "VolleyGet";
private static VolleyGetHeaders instance = null;
public RequestQueue requestQueue;
String finalToken;

private VolleyGetHeaders(Context context,String finalToken)
    {
    this.context=context;
    this.finalToken=finalToken;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());

    return;
    }
```

2) In your fragment send final token too when you are calling getInstance

for e.g.

```
VolleyGetHeaders.getInstance(getActivity(),finalToken);
```